# How do i remount an NFS volume on ESX 4.1 from the CLI

Tags: vmware-esx, nfs

Had a brief outage on the NFS server which has been fixed. One of the ESX hosts cant access VMs stored on that shared volume and appears not to have it mounted.

What is the command to remount an NFS backed esx datastore without rebooting the ESX host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esxcfg-nas -r` will restore previously-defined NAS volumes.

Adding a volume is done via `esxcfg-nas -a -o ip.add.re.ss -s /volumes/vol1/folder Datastore_Name`